# In Skyrim, Shadowmere has been lost for about 3 levels, how do I find her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, after the DBH quests, I went to the new Sanctuary, and did a lot of other quests, including the main story line, Dawnguard, Hearthfire, and just started the Dragonborn DLC. I've been wandering around with the Aura Whisper shout, and I've not found her. The last time I saw her was when I bought a horse from Whiterun, and rode it around until I reached Windhelm, and then it died due to a dragon. Shadowmere has not respawned (if dead), or turned up after fast-travelling. I tried reloading save files, but then I kept losing her. Is there a way to get her back?--

She wasn't at the black pool at EITHER Sanctuary and I still cannot find her. I've looked about everywhere and still she has not turned up and I've not found her.

Answer (score 2):

You rode another horse so she is not tied to you right now.. She should have walked back to the black pool by where you initialy got her during the DBH quests.

Comment: I've looked there, and all around where she should've been. If she died, she would have respawned by now. Where should I look besides the pool?